# Watching the flow of execution by “single-stepping” in PyScripter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscripter

**Ok, in fact, I did found a way how to single step into the code, but I still can't use the f4,f7 buttons to do it on my keyboard. Can anyone help ?**

I have an easy question which concerns the flow of execution : http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/functions.html

I'm referring to the following paragraph :

> In PyScripter, we can watch the flow of execution by “single-stepping” through any program. PyScripter will highlight each line of code just before it is about to be executed.
>   PyScripter also lets us hover the mouse over any variable in the program, and it will pop up the current value of that variable. So this makes it easy to inspect the “state snapshot” of the program — the current values that are assigned to the program’s variables.
>   This is a powerful mechanism for building a deep and thorough understanding of what is happening at each step of the way. Learn to use the single-stepping feature well, and be mentally proactive: as you work through the code, challenge yourself before each step: “What changes will this line make to any variables in the program?” and “Where will flow of execution go next?”
>
> Let us go back and see how this works with the program above that draws 15 multicolor squares. First, we’re going to add one line of magic below the import statement — not strictly necessary, but it will make our lives much simpler, because it prevents stepping into the module containing the turtle code.
>
> ```
> import turtle
> __import__("turtle").__traceable__ = False
> ```
>
> Now we’re ready to begin. Put the mouse cursor on the line of the program where we create the turtle screen, and press the F4 key. This will run the Python program up to, but not including, the line where we have the cursor. Our program will “break” now, and provide a highlight on the next line to be executed, something like this:

I don't know why, but when I press on F4 I only get my computer's options concerning the screen. Do you have any idea how I could correct this?

Thank you!